No web page was found for the web address
I've recently setup my own domain at another place I stay at and everything worked perfectly, since I had gotten home Chrome and other browsers keep seeming to give me No web page was found for the web address. I asked my friends and they don't get a problem.
I messed around with my DNS checking to make sure if any of that was the reason, It was not.
I cleared my browsers Cache and fully reset it and I didn't change anything
I tried another browser still without luck.
